# React: How can I prevent blinking when set state after requesting ajax?

Tags: reactjs, user-experience

The code below is `PostView` component I wrote, which shows a post on a blog. I decided to put ajax call on `componentDidMount` cycle, PostView component gets data by requesting GET `/blog?post=id` and sets state. I heard that one should not set state on `componentWillMount`. But this shows a blank page during 20ms or more... (I've tried to put ajax call on constructor, but it does not render. I choose to show `Loading` component which is spinner animation, but still awkwardly.)

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import $ from 'jquery';
import {
  Loading,
} from '../components';


class PostView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      content: '',
      fetchStatus: 'INIT',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const thisComponent = this;
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    $.get(`/blog?post=${id}`)
      .done((data) => {
        const { title, content } = data[0];
        thisComponent.setState({ title, content, fetchStatus: 'OK' });
      })
      .fail(() => { thisComponent.setState({ fetchStatus: 'FAIL' }); });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.fetchStatus !== 'OK') {
      return <Loading />
    }
    return (
      <div className="container padding">
        <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
        <p>{this.state.content}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

PostView.propTypes = {
  match: PropTypes.shape({
    params: PropTypes.object,
    isExact: PropTypes.bool,
    path: PropTypes.string,
    url: PropTypes.string,
  }),
};

PostView.defaultProps = {
  match: {
    params: {},
    isExact: 'false',
    path: '',
    url: '/',
  },
};

export default PostView;
```

Comment: You will not be able to see anything unless you get a response from the server, and componentDidMount is the ideal place to have API request. In your case you should show a loading spinner or something to indicate that the call has not yet resuted in a response

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri You mean that there is no other way to put ajax call in life cycle, So I should find another way to hide blinking?

Comment: componentDidMount is the right place to have Ajax calls, however you cannot do anything till your response is available so you have to have spinners or loading message

Comment: You can use a more smooth loading screens to make it look better. Check this article: [http://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html](http://cloudcannon.com/deconstructions/2014/11/15/facebook-content-placeholder-deconstruction.html) .

Comment: Self answer: Use single data store(e. g. Redux or mobX) and keep away API fetching from the view logics.

Comment: Or I can use promise to handling React.Component state for fetching status